# How to call two async functions every `n` and `m` seconds within a `while (true)` loop?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I have the following loop:

```
while (true) {
  await f();
  await g();
}
```

where `f` and `g` are defined as follows:

```
async function f() {
    await Promise.all([SOME_REQUEST_F, sleep(1000)])
}

async function g() {
    await Promise.all([SOME_REQUEST_G, sleep(5000)])
}
```

Also `sleep` is defined as follows:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

My intention is to have `SOME_REQUEST_F` awaited every one second, and `SOME_REQUEST_G` awaited every five seconds, hence wrapping them in `f` and `g`.

However, currently `g` is blocking the re-awaiting of `f` within the loop.

How to define `sleep`, such that if used in `g`, it blocks re-execution of `g`, but not that of `f`? Is there a better way to do what I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use two `while` loops instead:

```
(async () => {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    while (true) {
      await f();
    }
  });
  while (true) {
    await g();
  }
})();
```

The `setTimeout` there is needed to allow both `while`s to run concurrently, so that the initialization of one doesn't block the other from starting.